# How to post the data in a .csv file using a TCP sampler in JMeter (Load Testing)?

Tags: tcp, jmeter

I am getting stuck after creating a ".csv data config element" by inserting a file and a TCP Sampler with the proper Server ID and Port Number.
I have also created a thread group for it.

Answer (score 0):

Given your CSV files looks like:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and you want to send the next line on each iteration of each user you can do the following setup:

1. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) as a child of your TCP Sampler and configure it like:

   [image]
2. In the TCP Sampler use the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you specified in the "Variable Names" where needed:

   [image]
3. That's it, when you run your test the JMeter Variable placeholder will be substituted with the respective value from the CSV file:

   [image]

Comment: hi Dmitri thank you for helping me but i am having one more Question should i use the same script which you have used for tcp sampler